# ftp-authssl:// - what does it mean?

Tags: ftp

One of our programs uploads data to external FTP servers.
Connection (credentials and/or data) is encrypted.
It worked well until one of these external FTP servers installed one of the latest MS patches which has broken the encryption.

I am trying to set up a test environment to reproduce the issue.
The URL which is used by our program is

```
ftp-authssl://123.123.123.123:21
```

(actual IP is replaced by 123.123.123.123)

What does ftp-authssl:// mean?

The program is written in C#. It uses Eldos Secure Black Box (https://www.eldos.com/sbb/) library to upload data to FTP server. FTP server is IIS running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

This is explicit TLS mode for FTP, where you start with a plain connection and then issue a `AUTH TLS` (or older `AUTH SSL`) command and then upgrade the plain connection to TLS. This is similar to `STARTTLS` with other protocols like `SMTP` or `IMAP`. 
See [Wikipedia article to FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS#Explicit) for more details.

Comment: Many thanks!   WinSCP has "TLS explicit encryption" and "SSL explicit encryption" options. Which one corresponds to ftp-authssl:// ?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe TLS invokes the newer `AUTH TLS` command while SSL instead `AUTH SSL`. But, the meaning of both command is the same so I guess it does not matter.